# XML Query Attach appropriate ID

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath, sql-server-2012

I seem struggle with XML.  I am looking to get appropriate ID attached to each row

```
Declare @User table (id int,First_Name varchar(50),Last_Name varchar(50),EMail varchar(50))
Insert into @User values
(1,'John','Smith','john.smith@gmail.com'),
(2,'Jane','Doe'  ,'jane.doe@gmail.com')

Declare @XML xml
Set @XML = (Select * from @User for XML RAW)

Select ID    = 1 -- < dummy need actual id
      ,Item  = cast(x.v.query('local-name(.)') as varchar(100))
      ,Value = x.v.value('.','varchar(150)') 
 From  @xml.nodes('//@*') x(v)
```

My current result is.

```
ID  Item        Value
1   id          1
1   First_Name  John
1   Last_Name   Smith
1   EMail       john.smith@gmail.com
1   id          2
1   First_Name  Jane
1   Last_Name   Doe
1   EMail       jane.doe@gmail.com
```

My **Desired** result would be.

```
ID  Item        Value
1   id          1
1   First_Name  John
1   Last_Name   Smith
1   EMail       john.smith@gmail.com
2   id          2
2   First_Name  Jane
2   Last_Name   Doe
2   EMail       jane.doe@gmail.com
```

Comment: This is a good question: Copy'n'pasteable test scenario, own effort, wrong output, expeceted output and a clear and short description. If more questions were like that... :-) Voted it up!

Comment: Boah! I feel embarassed... Thank you!

Comment: @Shnugo Don't be embarassed, I've gotten a lot of mileage from your posts

Comment: Oh, great my glory is growing globally :-D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it like this:

Btw: You were pretty close!

```
Declare @User table (id int,First_Name varchar(50),Last_Name varchar(50),EMail varchar(50))
Insert into @User values
(1,'John','Smith','john.smith@gmail.com'),
(2,'Jane','Doe'  ,'jane.doe@gmail.com')

Declare @XML xml
Set @XML = (Select * from @User for XML RAW)

SELECT @XML;

/*
<row id="1" First_Name="John" Last_Name="Smith" EMail="john.smith@gmail.com" />
<row id="2" First_Name="Jane" Last_Name="Doe" EMail="jane.doe@gmail.com" />
*/
```

The first `.nodes()` will return with all `row` elements in single rows
The `CROSS APPLY .nodes(./@*)` will do a row based search for all attributes and deliver them as single rows.

```
Select r.value('@id','int') AS ID
      ,Attr.value('local-name(.)','varchar(max)') AS Item
      ,Attr.value('.','varchar(max)') AS Value
FROM @XML.nodes('/row') AS A(r)
CROSS APPLY A.r.nodes('./@*') AS B(Attr)
```

Comment: FABULOUS!   I tried countless combinations.   Thank you so very much.

Comment: nice job.. i couldn't find the row filter `('./@*')` anywhere..  i did find this though in case you want to exclude the id row.. `CROSS APPLY A.r.nodes('./@*[local-name(.)!="id"]')`

Comment: @JamieD77, good hint... As the `id` is mentioned in the *desired output* I'd assume it's wanted...

Comment: @JamieD77 Thanks, I WAS prepared to live with it even though it wasn't necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Just came across this question. Though answer to this question was already given, thought to answer it with different approach without using xquery.

You can achieve the same result using `CROSS APPLY` and [Table Value Constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx) like this -

```
Declare @User table (id int,First_Name varchar(50),Last_Name varchar(50),EMail varchar(50))
Insert into @User values
(1,'John','Smith','john.smith@gmail.com'),
(2,'Jane','Doe'  ,'jane.doe@gmail.com')

SELECT r.ID, t.* FROM @User r
CROSS APPLY (
    VALUES ('ID', cast(id as varchar)),
            ('First_Name', First_Name),
            ('Last_Name', Last_Name),
            ('EMail', EMail)
) t(Item, Value)
```

**Result**

```
ID  Item        Value
---------------------
1   ID          1
1   First_Name  John
1   Last_Name   Smith
1   EMail       john.smith@gmail.com
2   ID          2
2   First_Name  Jane
2   Last_Name   Doe
2   EMail       jane.doe@gmail.com
```

Comment: Appreciate the answer and I'm a big fan of this technique, but to the original question, I was looking for a dynamic approach   +1